# App consuming too much battery

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, cllocationmanager

After building the iOS app I wanted, I realized it's consuming way too much battery due to location services.

Background: My app makes a call to the server over network every time a user moves 10 meters (30 ft). This triggers the `didUpdateLocation` function. When that function is triggered I use `NSURLSession` to send the users coordinates to the server, that's really about it.

Now the issue lies in that I can't power down location services hardware by calling `locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()` after the first update because I won't get any subsequent updates when the user decides to move again. In addition, location services stays active while the app is in the background to monitor movement, also causing a drag on battery life. I have read almost everything about this issue when it comes to documentation and other questions on here.

A lot of other questions suggest using an `NSTimer` and calling the `startUpdatingLocation()` after an interval of time has passed by and I have received the first location update and called `stopUpdatingLocation` in my `didUpdateLocation` function. So I tried the following:

```
let timerAction = NSTimer(timeInterval: 6.0, target: self, selector: #selector(MapViewController().startLocationServices), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    timerAction.fire() 

func startLocationServices() {
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}
```

This hasn't worked for some reason or another. But my question really focuses around how I can save battery and make my app really energy efficient when I must monitor a user's movements in the foreground and background with the `distanceFilter = 10.0`?

Any suggestion maybe around what you have done or what you would recommend would be tremendously sought and appreciated.

Thank you!

**Edit**

@wain suggested using `allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled:timeout:`,

> Start the delivery of location updates before calling this method. The most common place to call this method is in your delegate’s locationManager:didUpdateLocations: method. After processing any new locations, call this method if you want to defer future updates until the distance or time criteria are met. If new events arrive and your app is in the background, the events are cached and their delivery is deferred appropriately.

Comment: Not gonna happen (across a wide range of device capabilities at least). Why do you need every 10m 24/7? Who is going to be interested in using this app? Is NATimer the only thing your research turned up?

Comment: The app drops pins as to where you went throughout the day. It's like a retrace your steps kind of thing. It's just for fun. I've seen other apps do this and do it efficiently in a relative way, like moves, uber and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up remedying this problem by using geofencing. I create a `CLCircularRegion` and call `startMonitoringForRegion(_:)`. Every time the user leaves the region (10 meters), I make a request to the server to see where he's at now and update the region. This use little to no battery and is exactly what I'm looking for. Look at the `CLLocationManager`, `CLLocationManagerDelegate` and `CLCircularRegion` classes on how to do this. I hope this will come in handy for someone.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 options:

1. Use `allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled:timeout:`
2. Use significant location change

Try the first, if it isn't available on the device you must sacrifice your 10m goal

Comment: `allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled:timeout` I did look at this in detail. Will I call it from my `viewDidLoad`? That's where I'm currently calling `startUpdatingLocation()` from.

Comment: Set it before starting location tracking, pay attention to delegate updates